# How to Hide PHP Undefined Error Messages with Echo?

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to have a div where it outputs the user information after the user submits it by using `echo`.

This is my code right now:

```html
<label class="input-fields" name="cust-name">
  Name <input type="text" id="cust[name]" placeholder="E.g. John Doe" required>
</label>
<label class="input-fields" name="cust-email">
  Email <input type="email" id="cust[email]" placeholder="E.g. john@mail.com" required>
</label>
<label class="input-fields" name="cust-mobile">
  Mobile <input type="text" id="cust[mobile]" placeholder="E.g. (04) 6172 5705" required>
</label>

<div class="order-info">Name: <?php echo $_POST["cust-name"]; ?></div>
<div class="order-info">Email: <?php echo $_POST["cust-email"]; ?></div>
<div class="order-info">Mobile: <?php echo $_POST["cust-mobile"]; ?></div>
```

It doesn't give the error in the example above, but on the page it gives me an error that says "Notice: Undefined index". How do I fix/hide this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons this is occurring:

Firstly, you have given the `name` attribute to the labels and not the inputs themselves. Labels need the `for` attribute so that they know which input they correspond with.

```html
<label class="input-fields" for="cust-name">
  Name <input type="text" name="cust-name" id="cust[name]" placeholder="E.g. John Doe" required>
</label>
```

Secondly, you are not checking to see whether the variables have been set in the first place. You need to wrap the HTML that shows the information in an `isset` statement:

```php
<?php if (isset($_POST["your-submit-button-name"])) { ?>
<div class="order-info">Name: <?php echo $_POST["cust-name"]; ?></div>
<div class="order-info">Email: <?php echo $_POST["cust-email"]; ?></div>
<div class="order-info">Mobile: <?php echo $_POST["cust-mobile"]; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you can also add        !empty($_POST["your-submit-button-name"]) .     as double check